# Iterate over BasicPrimitives OrgChart Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using basic primitives org chart to create a family tree. What I'd like to do is iterate over the items that have been rendered so I can save the json to the database. I've been looking over the site's reference and put this in my code:

```
alert(primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig.length);

$.each(primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig, function (key, value) {
     alert(value.Id);
 });

for (var i=0; i < primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig.length; i++)
   {
      alert(primitives.famdiagram.ItemConfig[i].Id);
   }
```

It gives me a length of 5, but when I try to iterate through the items with either jquery or javascript, nothing happens. How can I access the collection of items using basic primitives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work and I'd just have to rebuild the json string:

```
 var items = jQuery("#famdiagram").famDiagram("option", "items");
        $.each(items, function (key, value) {
            alert(value.id);
            alert(value.title);
            alert(value.parents);
        });
```

OR just save the items array in the DB as is.